# Подкатегории на сайте доступны по разным url (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Я столкнулась с тем, что на сайте подкатегории доступны по 2-м адресам. В первом случае в структуру url включается базовая категория. Во втором случае URL-адрес не содержит базовый URL-адрес.
Например, мой проект имеет категорию "*Малайзия*" и подкатегорию "*Борнео*". Я могу получить доступ к подкатегории "Борнео" через следующие URL:

1. https://life-thai.com/category/malaysia/borneo/
2. https://life-thai.com/category/borneo/

Как оставить только 1 URL, чтобы избежать дублирования?

У пермалинков на сайте структура `domain.com/%postname%/`, т.е. названия категорий и подкатегорий не включаются в url, по которому доступны страницы и записи. Проблема именно с подкатегориями.

Comment: Может так: /%category%/%postname%.html

Comment: Мне не нужно, чтобы в пермалинках к записям указывалась категория. Нужно убрать дублирование из пермалинка подкатегории.

Comment: <link rel="canonical" href="https://life-thai.com/" />

Comment: А что на счет WP_Rewrite? Стоит ли реализовать редирект через этот класс, или все же лучше оставить как есть, добавив rel=canonical?

Comment: Редирект там, где он не нужен - плохо. Лучше просто выводить (там, где это нужно) канонические ссылки. Например, в комментариях, если они у вас на сайте есть, их лучше не показвать. Прочитайте, например: https://wp-kama.ru/function/rel_canonical

Comment: спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Такая же проблема
Ставлю 301 редирект с тех подкатегорий, которые не нужны
В sitemap все ок